# PHP/MySQL - Not posting to database

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine

This PHP script is meant to post a users name into a database but it doesnt seem to work properly. The project in unity wont post it correctly and going straight to IP

```
ADDRESS/addUser.php?NAME=Ryan
```

also doesnt work. It auto increments the ID as it should but the name field is always blank.

```
<?php
         //Connect
        $sql_connect = mysql_connect("IP", "USER", "PASS") or die ("no DB Connection");

        //Select Database
        mysql_select_db("practiceCrim") or die ("DB not found");

        //Post Info To Var
        $name = $_POST['NAME'];

        //Query
         $query = "INSERT INTO Users (Name)
         VALUES ('$name')";

         //Run The Query, Get Result
        $result = mysql_query( $query, $sql_connect );

         //Not Really Needed For You
         if(!$result)
         {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
         }

        //Close The Connection
        mysql_close($sql_connect);
    ?>
```

Comment: It look like you're getting the name field from the PHP $_POST variable. But your example passes the name field as a GET parameter. Could this be the problem?

Comment: How would i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you're getting the name field from the PHP $_POST variable. But your example passes the name field as a GET parameter.

To fix this, you have two options. If you *only* want to allow name to be passed as a GET parameter, then you need to do this:

```
$name = $_GET["NAME"];
```

If you want to allow name to be passed as *either* a GET or a POST parameter, you can do this:

```
$name = $_REQUEST["NAME"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should replace  **$name = $_POST['NAME']** with **$name = $_GET['NAME']** or **$name = $_REQUEST['NAME']** 
`where $_REQUEST is default  but don't use $_REQUEST`